# SQL: Need to check columns for values that exist in another column

Tags: sql, ms-access

Using SQL, my job is to fetch the SSN of students who enrolled in a course without enrolling in that course’s prerequisite(s). I'm using Access. The tables I need are as follows:

- STUDENT (SSN, SNAME, MAJOR, DOB, ADDRESS)
- ENROLLED (SSN, CID, GRADE)
- PREQ (CID, PREQCID, PASSINGGRADE, NOTE)

[Here's what I've done so far.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RAVe0.png)

```
select * 
from
    (select SSN, CID from ENROLLED) AS enrolled 
left join
    (select CID, PREQCID FROM PREQ) AS prereq ON enrolled.CID = prereq.CID;
```

What I'm missing is how to check each row of the same student on the condition `WHERE enrolled.CID = prereq.CID` for a PREQCID that's NOT in `enrolled.CID`.

Is what I'm asking for here a loop? Am I on the right track? Please keep in mind this I'm in an introductory course so the simplest of solutions is preferable.

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify earlier; this is Access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this, but this gets you your result:

```
Select S.SSN, E.CID From Student S
Inner Join Enrolled E on E.SSN = S.SSN
Where E.CID IN (Select CID From PREQ Where Preqcid NOT IN
(Select CID From Enbrolled Where SSN = S.SSN))
```

Comment: Thanks. This works fine and I could understand it since our instructor has been using nested queries like this, even if they're a bit confusing.

Comment: I think Lee Mac's method using Not Exists is definitely cleaner and more optimized than using 2 nested sub-queries. On a large table, that could make a difference in execution time.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way using `not exists`:

```sql
select e1.ssn 
from enrolled e1 left join preq p on e1.cid = p.cid
where 
    p.preqcid is not null and 
    not exists (select 1 from enrolled e2 where e2.ssn = e1.ssn and e2.cid = p.preqcid)
```

This is essentially stating:

*"Select the `ssn` for all enrollments where there is a prerequisite course and the prerequisite course ID does not exist in the table of enrollments for that `ssn`."*

I use `select 1` purely for optimisation - we don't care about the values held by the nested query, only whether or not the nested query returns one or more records.

---

You could also write this using joins as:

```sql
select e1.ssn 
from 
    (
        enrolled e1 left join preq p on e1.cid = p.cid
    ) 
    left join enrolled e2 on 
    p.preqcid = e2.cid and e1.ssn = e2.ssn
where
    e2.cid is null
```

Here, the `enrolled` table is referenced twice: the first is left joined on the table of prerequisite courses for each course, and the second is left joined on the prerequisite course ID and the `ssn` from the original enrollment.

The `where` clause then causes records to be selected for which the link on the prerequisite course is `null` for the given `ssn`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work if analytic functions and CTEs are available:

```
with d as (
    select ssn, cid,
        count(distinct p.cid) over (partition by e.ssn, e.cid) ecnt, ,
        count(distinct e.cid) over (partition by e.ssn, p.cid) pcnt
    from enrolled e left outer join preq p on p.cid = e.cid
)
select distinct ssn, cid from d
where ecnt = pcnt;
```

Comment: Unfortunately MS Access does not support `with`, `over` or `partition`, and `distinct` can only follow `select`.

Comment: @LeeMac I wrote that before OP clarified.